How to determine the solana main instruction?
I am working on solana transactions, i already do a decode instructions using IDL.
How to determine the main instruction of a transaction?
I am curious about the third party API like shyft/helius. How they determined it?
they have transaction->type on the root of object, and sometimes they don't include all of the instruction on their transaction->actions field.

There is no "main instruction" in a Solana transaction. All instructions in the transaction get executed atomically(if one fails, all fail).
A Solana transaction consists of the signatures and a transaction message. The instructions for a transaction can be found in the transaction message.
read more about transactions here: https://solana.com/docs/core/transactions
Third-party RPC providers parse and do more computation to present the transaction data in a more readable format compared to using the getTransaction.

Thanks for the reply. it's clear now.
